# How to get the closest element from a javascript array using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array like this

```
var array1= [10,20,30,40,50];
```

Is there any method using which i can get the closest array element to a given number ? Ex: if i pass 26, It should return 30 ( 26 is closest to 30). If i pass 42, It should return 40.

Any thoughts ? Should i iterate thru each elements ? Is there any methods available for this in jQuery ?

Comment: I don't believe there is anything in jquery which is going to help you with this.  Are the elements guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: I don't think JQuery has any function that solves this problem. Furthermore, if array is unordered, you would need to iterate through all the array and find the answer.

Comment: Just sort it and loop through it.. really no built in function for jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple with a for loop. No jQuery magic necessary:

```
function getClosestNum(num, ar)
{
    var i = 0, closest, closestDiff, currentDiff;
    if(ar.length)
    {
        closest = ar[0];
        for(i;i<ar.length;i++)
        {           
            closestDiff = Math.abs(num - closest);
            currentDiff = Math.abs(num - ar[i]);
            if(currentDiff < closestDiff)
            {
                closest = ar[i];
            }
            closestDiff = null;
            currentDiff = null;
        }
        //returns first element that is closest to number
        return closest;
    }
    //no length
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You'll want to change that `if(closest)` because having 0 in the array breaks it.  http://jsfiddle.net/36wUL/

Comment: I'm also a little iffy about you having a local variable named "closest" shadowing the name of the function.

Comment: You also probably don't need to recheck the current diff at every iteration :S

Answer (score 5):

If performance is a concern (very large array) and the array is ordered (as in the example), you may want to consider a [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).  You can probably find one pre-written for javascript but may need to modify slightly to handle your "closest" piece once the algorithm reaches the end.

Comment: Right, I asked in the comments if it was always ordered, he hasn't answer yet.  I'll update the answer to be more clear.  I'm unsure which is faster, just iterating or sorting and then binary searching if it is unordered.  I'm too far off from my college algorithms class.

Comment: if only it was a linked list.. then he would have O(nlgn) :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have ranges of 10 that are sequential, it can be as simple as this:

```
var array1= [10,20,30,40,50];
var n = 23;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 10 ) - 1,  0);
```

Examples:

```
var array1= [10,20,30,40,50];
var n = 23;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 10 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 20

var n = 28;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 10 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 30

var n = 1;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 10 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 10
```

**Examples:** http://jsfiddle.net/GTrNt/

Should work the same with other ranges, like 25:

```
var array1= [25,50,75,100,125];
var n = 23;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 25 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 25

var n = 48;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 25 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 50

var n = 1;
var idx = Math.max( Math.round( n / 25 ) - 1,  0);

alert( array1[ idx ] );   // 25
```

**Examples:** http://jsfiddle.net/GTrNt/1

Comment: If that's the case you can just get rid of the array all together.

Comment: @kingjiv: You certainly could.

Comment: @down-voter: Care to explain? Or was this retaliation for my last post?

Comment: Offsetting upvote because I really really hate when people do that.  Although I did get an upvote today on my answer here so it could just be someone sweeping over the post.

Comment: @kingjiv: Thanks for the offset; there was just a bit of curious timing with this one. Not a big deal, but I do tend to call downers out for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/nwUbV/1/

With binary search. If it's a really big array though, you'll need to implement a better sorting function such as Quicksort so that performance doesn't suffer.

Answer (score -1):

I used jQuery to create the loop (just because I always have jQuery loaded) - it's not really necessary. And this may not be the most efficient method available. But here's a quick function that will do what you need:

```
var array1 = Array(20, 30, 40, 50);
var closestindex = findClosest(42, array1);
alert('Closest is '+array1[closestindex]);

function findClosest(needle, haystack) {
    var offset = 10000;
    var closest = 0;
    $.each(haystack, function(i) {
        if (haystack[i] <= needle) {
            var localoffset = needle - haystack[i];
        } else {
            var localoffset = haystack[i] - needle;
        }
        if (localoffset <= offset) {
            offset = localoffset;
            closest = i;
        }
    });
    return closest;
}
```